# Why is it bad to pass an ID to a thread in the following way?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I am currently trying to learn POSIX threads and made the simple code that you can see below.
I have been told that it is bad to pass an ID to a thread as you can see I did in this code snippet:

```
    int ID0= 0;
    int ID1 = 1;

    pthread_create(&thread_zero, NULL, thread_function, (void*)&ID0);
    pthread_create(&thread_one, NULL, thread_function, (void*)&ID1);
```

Why is that?

Also, would it be better to use pthread_self?

**The full code**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *thread_function(void *arg)
{

  for(int i =0; i<=10;i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello # " << i<< " From thread : " <<*((int*)arg) << std::endl;
        sleep(1);
    }

std::cout <<"Thread "<<*((int*)arg)<< " terminates" << std::endl;

pthread_exit(NULL);

}

int main(){
    pthread_t thread_zero;
    pthread_t thread_one;

    int ID0= 0;
    int ID1 = 1;

    pthread_create(&thread_zero, NULL, thread_function, (void*)&ID0);
    pthread_create(&thread_one, NULL, thread_function, (void*)&ID1);

    std::cout << "main: Creating threads" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "main: Wating for threads to finish" << std::endl;

    pthread_join(thread_zero, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread_one, NULL);

    std::cout<<"Main: Exiting"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Forget posix threads. There are newer, better and portable standards in C++11.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis
I know. But I'm trying to learn it out of necessity.

Comment: If I'd have to guess, I would say that it a general advice in case someone doesn't join the thread and when the function ends, the ID variable goes out of scope, in which case the thread will get a dangling pointer.

Comment: If you pass a pointer to an object with automatic storage duration, you have to ensure that the object's lifetime does not end while the created thread might still be accessing the object. Also, in C accessing another thread's automatic storage duration objects is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is that?

There is nothing wrong with your code, *so long as* you ensure that the `ID0` and `ID1` do not go out of scope before you join your threads, *and* that either thread does not modify `ID0` and `ID1` without proper synchronization.

In general, when passing an entity into thread that is not larger than `(void*)`, it is *safer* to pass it by value, like so:

```
pthread_create(&tid, NULL, fn, (void*)ID0);
```

When done that way, `ID0` can go out of scope with no danger that the new thread will access dangling stack, and no danger of a data race (which is undefined behavior).